# Unable to run (Python) bottle app using gunicorn

Tags: python, python-3.x, gunicorn, bottle

I am just getting started with Bottle. I have found a sample app on [GitHub](https://github.com/saipraveen-a/bottle-example). The sample just has a server.py file which looks like below

```
import bottle

APP = bottle.Bottle()

@APP.get('/')
def index():
  return '<p>Hello</p>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  bottle.run(application=APP)
```

The requirements.txt file has

```
bottle
gunicorn
```

as dependencies. I am using Python 3.7.2. After running pip install -r requirements.txt, I ran python server.py. The server starts up without error on Port 8080

I tried running the server using gunicorn as below

```
gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 server:app
```

This gives an error and the server doesn't start. What's wrong with the gunicorn command?

Comment: `app` is not the same as `APP`.

Comment: gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 server:APP works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 server:APP

Thanks to Klaus D for pointing out